# OneDrive for business : Can my one drive for business folders share with multiple share-point accounts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I want to share "one drive for business" folder's with my another multiple SharePoint accounts based on folders level permission applied to each folder to accessible it to particular account so is this possible such operation ?

We implemented C# based MVC portal to access one drive for business using graph api so can we achieve above operation inside the portal ?

Comment: Do you want to share some folder to someone?

Comment: Yes. Need to provide access to several folders to another office 365 SharePoint accounts